# Concatenating vector Rect in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have two rectangle vectors

```
std::vector<cv::Rect>faces;
std::vector<cv::Rect>windows;
```

I need to concatenate windows with faces...for that I wrote the code as

```
 int fsize=faces.size();
    for(int i=0;i<windows.size();i++)
    {
        faces[fsize]=windows[i];
        fsize++;
    }
```

But I thk this code is creating segmentation faults...anybody know anything betr..or any built in functions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing `faces` with `windows` and if `windows` have more elements than `faces` you access out of boundary of `faces`.

If you really mean `Concatenating` instead of `replacing`:

```
faces.reserve(faces.size() + windows.size());
faces.insert(faces.end(), windows.begin(), windows.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use insert:

```
faces.insert(faces.end(), windows.begin(), windows.end());
```

or to move the contents:

```
faces.insert(faces.end(), std::make_move_iterator(windows.begin()), 
                          std::make_move_iterator(windows.end()));
```